# No Route Matches error - with Nested Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-routing

I have the following Nested Resource in my `routes.rb` file

```
  resource :issuer do
    resources :certificates
  end
```

My Models:

```
class Issuer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :certificates
end

class Certificate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :issuer
end
```

**I get the following error when i visit:** `/issuer/2/certificates`

`No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"certificates"}`

Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** : MY `rake routes`

```
    issuer_certificates GET    /issuer/:issuer_id/certificates(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"certificates"}
                        POST   /issuer/:issuer_id/certificates(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"certificates"}
 new_issuer_certificate GET    /issuer/:issuer_id/certificates/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"certificates"}
edit_issuer_certificate GET    /issuer/:issuer_id/certificates/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"certificates"}
     issuer_certificate GET    /issuer/:issuer_id/certificates/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"certificates"}
                        PUT    /issuer/:issuer_id/certificates/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"certificates"}
                        DELETE /issuer/:issuer_id/certificates/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"certificates"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use resources (plural) instead of resource in refer to :issuer. So please try this:

```
resources :issuers do
   resources :certificates
end
```

and `issuers/2/certificates` will work.

Comment: please look at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources. This is exactly your case resolved my way :)

Answer (score 1):

In your routes.rb file you are defining issuer as a singular resource

```
  resource :issuer do         # <-----  using resource instead of resources
    resources :certificates
  end
```

With singular resources, the routes you get won't allow an :id to be matched, so in your example,

```
issuer/2/certificates
```

it's the "2" that's giving you grief.  You should either get rid of it or define :issuer as a standard (non-singular) resource in your routes.rb file.

Comment: Never mind.  From the rake routes output you posted, I see that issuer_ids are matched.  You probably just made a typo in routes.rb in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `PUT` defined for `/issuer/2/certificates`. instead you have it defined for `/issuer/2/certificates/123`. That's why you get that error.

If you are trying to edit the `certificate` then make sure you generate a correct link and include `certificate_id`.